# Batch class to update date from Notes and Attachments

Tags: apex, batch

I am Trying to write a batch class which will update the LastTranscationDate field on Account.
 when any note or attachment is added or edited  it will update the LastTranscationDate as Notes or Attachment latest lastmodified date.

```
 global class Core_Acc_Transaction_date implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful{   

 global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){  
      String query = 'SELECT Id,Name,Last_Transaction_Date__c from Account';
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}


    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> scope){ 


        /// Content Notes
        List<ContentDocumentLink> ContentNotesLst=[Select ContentDocument.Title,ContentDocument.CreatedDate,LinkedEntityId,ContentDocument.LastModifiedDate from ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityId IN:Scope];

        Map<Id,ContentDocumentLink> ContentNotesMap= new Map<Id,ContentDocumentLink>();

        for(ContentDocumentLink CDl: ContentNotesLst){
            ContentNotesMap.put(CDl.LinkedEntityId,CDl);
        }
        List<Account> ContentAcc=new List<Account>();
        for(Account Opp:scope){
            if(Opp.Last_Transaction_Date__c < ContentNotesMap.get(Opp.Id).ContentDocument.LastModifiedDate){
                system.debug('******Notes');
              Opp.Last_Transaction_Date__c = Date.valueOf(ContentNotesMap.get(Opp.Id).ContentDocument.LastModifiedDate);
                contentAcc.add(Opp);
            }
        }


        //Attachments

        List<Attachment> Attachmentslst=[Select id,ParentId,Name,LastModifiedDate from Attachment where Parent.id IN:scope];
        Map<Id,Attachment> AttachmentMap= new Map<Id,Attachment>();
        for(Attachment Att: Attachmentslst){
            AttachmentMap.put(Att.ParentId,Att);
        }
        system.debug('*******Attachmentslst'+Attachmentslst);
        List<Account> AttchOpp=new List<Account>();
        for(Account Opp:scope){

            if(Opp.Last_Transaction_Date__c < AttachmentMap.get(Opp.Id).LastModifiedDate){
                system.debug('******Notes');
                Opp.Last_Transaction_Date__c = Date.valueOf(AttachmentMap.get(Opp.Id).LastModifiedDate);
                AttchOpp.add(Opp);
            }
        }


    // I need to update the latest date in Account.. Not able to figure out the latest date in AttchOpp ,ContentAcc lists


    }

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){ 
}

}
```

edit: fixed single quote missing in code.

Comment: Please edit your question to specify what exact problem you are facing or what is not working from the code.

Comment: I need to update the latest date in Account.. Not able to figure out how to get the latest date AttchOpp ,ContentAcc lists

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the batch here, you can use the ContentVersion trigger to track updated notes/attachments.

```
trigger ContentVersionTrigger on ContentVersion (after insert, after update) {

    Id[] docIds = new List<Id>();
    for(ContentVersion cv: trigger.new){
        docIds.add(cv.ContentDocumentId);
    }

    List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
    ContentDocumentLink[] cdLinks = [SELECT Id, LinkedEntityId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE ContentDocumentId IN :docIds];
    for(ContentDocumentLink cdLink: cdLinks){
        if(cdLink.LinkedEntityId.getSobjectType() == Account.getSobjectType()){
            Account acc = new Account(Id = cdLink.LinkedEntityId);
            // update accout field here
            accounts.add(acc); 
        }
    }

    update accounts;
}
```

Comment: OP appears to be using "classic" Attachment rather than Files which would be ContentVersions; that said, you approach would work as well with trigger on Attachment

Comment: @cropredy Initially, I had thought of this but I think ContentVersion Trigger run for notes and attachment as well.

Answer (score 0):

Can anyone help me to implement this batch
global class CalculateLastInteraction implements Database.Batchable
{
/*
* Batch : CalculateLastInteraction
Description : a batch that calculates last interaction date/time on Account
LastInteraction must be = Maximum of LastEvent/LastNewsletter on child contacts.

```
    Example : 
    
    Account ABCompany has 2 contacts (Contact A and Contact B)
    
    Contact A has LastEvent =  13/10/2022 09:22 and LastNewsletter =  11/09/2022 09:22
    Contact B has LastEvent = 02/04/2022 19:25 and LastNewsletter = 01/10/2022 07:14
    
    The batch should update LastInteraction of ABCompany to 13/10/2022 09:22**/
   //Methode Start
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
{
    //Collecter les données 

    String Query='Select LastEvent__c,LastNewsletter__c from Contact';
    String Query1='SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id IN(SELECT AccountId,LastEvent__c,LastNewsletter__c FROM Contact)';
    return Database.getQueryLocator(Query1);
}
//Methode execute
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,List<Contact> ConList)
{
    for(Contact c :ConList)
    {
        DateTime value;
        Account a=new Account();
        if(c.LastEvent__c>c.LastNewsletter__c)
        {
            value=c.LastEvent__c;
        }
        else if(c.LastNewsletter__c>c.LastEvent__c)
        {
            value=c.LastNewsletter__c;
        }
        a.LastInteraction__c=value;
        update a;
    }
}
//Methode finish
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
{
    System.debug('Job finished');
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! This is a Questions & Answers site, not a threaded forum. Please see the various pertinent/relevant notes in [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers), and be aware that your "answer" will likely be deleted. You could ask a [new question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), but if you do please elaborate on what you mean by "help me implement:" Are you getting an error? If so, include *exact* error text (and stack trace). Are you getting some unexpected result? If so, explain.